# Export transition layers from R

Tags: r

I am wondering if there is a way to export, and therefore save, transition layers generated using the `transition()` function in the gdistance package. I am working  with a large starting raster that takes a long long time to turn into a transition layer and it would be nice to save it so that `costDistance()` runs later go faster. Thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can save most R objects to disk using:

```
  saveRDS(object, 'file.rds')
```

You can then read it again with:

```
  object <- readRDS('file.rds')
```

(There are a few exceptions, such as proxy objects or objects than contain an external pointer)